# Multiple fonts of the same family in axf:font-face tag

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

I am confused about the `<axf:font-face>` tag, and I think I am not using it correctly.

I specified the font Helvetica with `font-weight=300` and `font-weight=100`:

```
<fo:declarations>
    <axf:font-face src="url(Helvetica-01.ttf)" font-family="Helvetica" font-style="normal" font-weight="300"/>
    <axf:font-face src="url(Helvetica-Light-05.ttf)" font-family="Helvetica" font-style="normal" font-weight="100"/>
</fo:declarations>
```

Later in the stylesheet, I want to print some text with font-weight="100":

```
<fo:block font-family="Helvetica" font-weight="100">SOME TEXT</fo:block>
```

But in the FO output I see `font-weight="300"`, instead.

Is there a mistake in how I specify the fonts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which AH Formatter version are you using?  Are you getting any error messages about not finding font files?

I get the expected font weights when using AH Formatter V6.6 (with different font files because I don't have your Helvetica):

```
<fo:declarations>
  <axf:font-face src="url(SourceSansPro-Black.otf)" font-family="Helvetica" font-style="normal" font-weight="300"/>
  <axf:font-face src="url(SourceSansPro-Regular.otf)" font-family="Helvetica" font-style="normal" font-weight="100"/>
</fo:declarations>
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block font-family="Helvetica">Hello, world.</fo:block>
        <fo:block font-family="Helvetica" font-weight="100">Hello, world.</fo:block>
    </fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>
```

Comment: I am using Formatter 6.2 Lite, but the production environment is a server with Formatter 6.6. Which answers my question: font-face was only introduced in 6.3, and never in Formatter Lite. Of course fonts would not work.